# How can I receive percent encoded slashes with Django on App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Django with Google's App Engine.

I want to send information to the server with percent encoded slashes.  A request like `http:/localhost/turtle/waxy%2Fsmooth` that would match against a URL like `r'^/turtle/(?P<type>([A-Za-z]|%2F)+)$'`.  The request gets to the server intact, but sometime before it is compared against the regex the %2F is converted into a forward slash.

What can I do to stop the %2Fs from being converted into forward slashes?  Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just change the regexp to use the non-encoded version?

Comment: We're using a RESTful design and have other regexes that look like `r'^/turtle/(?P<type>([A-Za-z]|%2F)+)/shell$'`.  We want to distinguish between slashes that are part of the URL hierarchy and slashes that are part of a turtle name.

Comment: I will add this to my list of requirements that I use when evaluating candidate Python web frameworks.

Comment: You say it's "sometimes" converted - under what circumstances?

Comment: It says "sometime".  I meant that at some point after it gets to the server but before it is compared to the regex the %2F is converted to a forward slash.

Comment: Ah. It sounds like Django is doing it - I would suggest trying to find where, precisely, it is happening. some WSGI middleware, for example, would let you see if it happens before Django, or in Django.

Comment: I'd love to see a reliable solution to this problem. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a portable way to do it behind wsgi. In my own service, I ended up using the query string to pass arguments that might contain slashes. Not as pretty as using the path alone, but at least it works reliably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.environ['PATH_INFO']` is decoded, so you lose that information.  Probably `os.environ['REQUEST_URI']` is available, and if it is available it is not decoded.  Django only reads PATH_INFO.  You could probably do something like:

```
request_uri = environ['REQUEST_URI']
request_uri = re.sub(r'%2f', '****', request_uri, re.I)
environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(request_uri)
```

Then all cases of %2f are replaced with `****` (or whatever you want to use).

Comment: What sets REQUEST_URI?  I don't see it in pep 333's required wsgi variable list.

Comment: It's not required in PEP 333, but it is widely set as part of CGI (or CGI-like) requests.  On GAE if it exists, then it is certain to keep existing.  It is the complete request path, with no URL unencoding done to it.

Comment: `os.environ['REQUEST_URI']` is not available on GAE.

Comment: Then the information is lost and there's no way to distinguish %2f from /

Comment: Another technique that works for GData is that you have things like `/{http:%2f%2ffoo}attr/` (which by the time it gets to WSGI looks like `/{http://foo}attr/`), but because it uses nested braces you can parse out the chunks.  You could design your URLs similarly.

Comment: I think that the suggestion of bracketing the names is probably the best solution short of hacking Django.  Thanks for your help, Ian!

Comment: Interesting approach.  Beware, though: curly braces are not valid characters in the latest generic URI syntax rules ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2 ) and they were specifically disallowed in the previous rules ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-2.4.3 ).

Comment: Quite right, they should be escaped like `/%7bhttp:%2f%2ffoo%7dattr/`